# making HTML with page resolution

Tags: html, css

So, I'm trying to do an application for a tablet, and my resolution of the screen is `1280x720`. I'm using **w3.css** to create it.

What i'm trying to get for a response is a way to make all my `div` and tables and everything just inside of that screen.

I made the screen with a div with the resolution i wanted.

[my menu page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGycf.png)

Comment: Use responsive css to start with (i.e. `width: 50%`) don't set things according to screen resolution, because that changes from device to device. Then just start working through different css tutorials to get a handle on what needs to be done.

Comment: I don't want to change devices. What I'm doing is just for one device, with that resolution.

Comment: Will you ever show this to a friend on an older tablet? Will you ever use an updated version of this tablet? Will a user ever flip the tablet vertically instead of horizontally? ... Use responsive css.

Comment: Where is the problem, what have you tried? The way you asked your question `width: 100%;` solves your problem. Also, like @Kallmanation said **use relative units**, even if you don't make it fully responsive.

Comment: I'm not gonna use it on an older tablet, and not with an updated version, and the tablet can't flip.. I'm trying to use responsive css but I can't make it work the way i want it to

Comment: I tried percentages, but it didn't work

Comment: Well What did you try? What didn't work? Read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I will read that. I'm sorry, I'm new and I just want this project done, sorry. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to include all your style inside media queries

```
 @media only screen 
      and (min-device-width: 768px) 
      and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

    html, body{
    width:100%;
    padding:0 20px;
    }

    .container{
    width: 1024px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries like so:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) and (max-height: 720px) {
    /* Your CSS for 1280x720 and below */
}
```

See more here:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp